# Trying to iterate through an object's values and insert into new object (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create a series of new objects using the values from an existing object to push to my database.

Here is the existing object:

```
{
  name: 'Pasta',
  method: 'Cook pasta',
  ingredients: [
    { measure: 'tbsp', quantity: '1', ingredient_name: 'lemon' },
    { measure: 'g', quantity: '1', ingredient_name: 'salt' },
    { measure: 'packet', quantity: '1', ingredient_name: 'spaghetti' },
    { measure: 'litre', quantity: '1', ingredient_name: 'water' }
  ]
}
```

Basically I have a function that inserts and returns the id of the recipe into one table, then inserts and returns/or finds the ids of the relevant ingredients and the final part (with which I am struggling) is to combine the returned `recipe_id`, `ingredient_id` and the correct `measure` and `quantity` (as written in the object above).

Here is where I have gotten to:

```
//starting point is here
async function addNewRecipe(newRecipe, db = connection) {
  console.log(newRecipe)
  const recipeDetails = {
    recipe_name: newRecipe.name,
    recipe_method: newRecipe.method,
  }
  const ingredientsArray = newRecipe.ingredients

  const [{ id: recipeId }] = await db('recipes')
    .insert(recipeDetails)
    .returning('id')

  const ingredientsWithIds = await getIngredients(ingredientsArray) //returns an array of ids


  ingredientsWithIds.forEach((ingredientId) => {
    let ingredientRecipeObj = {
      recipe_id: recipeId, //works
      ingredient_id: ingredientId, //works
      measure: newRecipe.ingredients.measure, //not working - not sure how to match it with the relevant property in the newRecipe object above.
      quantity: newRecipe.ingredients.quantity,//not working - not sure how to match it with the relevant property in the newRecipe object above.
    }
    //this is where the db insertion will occur
  })
}
```

The desired output would be:

```
ingredientRecipeObj = {
      recipe_id: 1
      ingredient_id: 1
      measure: tbsp
      quantity: 1
} then insert this into db

followed by:
ingredientRecipeObj = {
     recipe_id: 1
     ingredient_id: 2
     measure: g
     quantity: 1
} then insert into db

etc. etc.
```

Comment: What's your expected/desired output?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the function "getIngredients" returns only the IDs. Once you have fetched them, you have no way of knowing which ID is for which ingredient. You would have to change that method to make it return an array of both the ID and the ingredient name. Then you could find the ingredient in the ingredient array.

Comment: thanks for the clarifying questions - I have added desired output to OP. Essentially the ``forEach`` would create an object with the recipe's id, and then each ingredient's id from the ``ingredientIds`` array and then the relevant measure and quantity from the ``newRecipe`` object (which is exampled in OP). Each ``ingredientObj`` would then be inserted into db.

Comment: @FredrikWallén seems accurate, just not sure how best to join them up?

Comment: The getIngredients would have to return an array of objects that have the ID and the ingredient name. How to do that would depend on what the getIngredients method looks like.

Comment: It doesn't need the name - just the id which is returned then the measure/quantity is already inside the newRecipe object which is passed into function as a parameter

Comment: Even if you do not need it in the end, you'll need it to know which ids belong to which ingredient. I'll post an answer so I can post code more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the function "getIngredients" returns only the IDs. Once you have fetched them, you have no way of knowing which ID is for which ingredient. One way to change that is to make the method return an array of both the ID and the ingredient name. Then you could match them like this:

```
const ingredientsWithIds = await getIngredients(ingredientsArray) //now an array of objects with ingredient_name and id

ingredientsWithIds.forEach((ingredient) => {
    const recipeIngredient = ingredientsArray.find(ri => ri.ingredient_name === ingredient.ingredient_name)
    const ingredientRecipeObj = {
      recipe_id: recipeId,
      ingredient_id: ingredient.id, 
      measure: recipeIngredient.measure, 
      quantity: recipeIngredient.quantity,
    }
    //this is where the db insertion will occur
  })
```

Since you haven't posted the "getIngredients" function it is hard to say exactly how to adapt it to return the name as well.